# i want to start service when application comes to background and stop service when application is in foreground

Tags: android

I have created one application in which I want to start service when application comes to background and stop service when application is in foreground.
I used onPause() and onResume(), but i have to handle it in every activity. So, it's called when i move from one activity to another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used onPause() and onResume(), but i have to handle it in every activity.

Create a "base" `Activity`...

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    // Put any methods you need here that are common to all of your Activities

}
```

Then simply extend your base `Activity` for all of the `Activity` classes you create...

```
public class ActivityOne extends MyBaseActivity {

    ...

}
```

In this way all of your `Activities` will automatically handle what you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use a boolean flag.

```
boolean movingInApp = false;
....
movingInApp = true;
Intent intent...
.....
public void onPause() {
    if(!movingInApp) {
        //start service
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    movingInApp = false;
    //Stop service
}
```

By setting the value of `movingInApp` to true before launching any intent etc, you can prevent your app from starting the service. Remember to set it to false again later in your `onResume()` method. If the system makes your app go to the background, this will be false, and your service will be started.